# Run interactive program with apache ant

Tags: ant, build

Ant seems to be pretty bad as running interactive program.

So for instance, a typical run would looks something like this, right?

```
main:
     [mytask1] <task output>
     [myatask2] <task output>
     ...
     [mytaskn] <task output>
```

Is there any way to get rid of those labels `[mytask1], ...` so I can run an interactive program still looking nicely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass `-emacs` or `-e` to ant when you run it these "banners" or "adornments" will be removed. See [the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) and [other notes on how to enable this](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#emacs-mode).